# Release Triggered by build does not contain TFS metadata

Tags: tfs, release-management, continuous-deployment, ms-release-management

Weve been trying to implement Microsoft's Release Management into our CI\CD process between trusted and untrusted servers.

The TFBuild server drops the compiled files onto the drop folder via FTP as post build script, and goes on to trigger the Release process

In the build process i have configured the components to be taken from an UNC: C:\BuildDrop[Build]\Artifacts

The release keeps failing on an error cannot find files under "C:\BuildDrop\\Artifacts...." and u can see the BuildNumber is missing.
 after some research in the logs i found out that the metadata of the tfs transfered to the Release server is empty and looks as follows

```
<Metadata>
<BuildDefinition></BuildDefinition>
<BuildNumber></BuildNumber>
<PackageLocation></PackageLocation>
<ServerName>RMServerName</ServerName>
<ServerDnsName>DNSName</ServerDnsName>
<TeamProject></TeamProject>
<TfsCollection></TfsCollection>
<TfsUrl></TfsUrl>
<TfsUrlWithCollection></TfsUrlWithCollection>  </Metadata>
```

(This was captured using *DeploymentAgent.exe debug start*)

Note: same user running the DeploymentAgent and the BuildService and has TFSCollection Admin authorization and Administrator on both servers

Comment: i have also went through this: [link](http://incyclesoftware.zendesk.com/entries/24896342-My-TFS-connection-is-not-working)

Comment: What build process template are you using?

Comment: ReleaseGitTemplate.12.xaml